# Tring to figure out a particular Ruby on Rails idiom: Dynamically accessing an object's member associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

This should be simple, but I can't find the answer.

I'm trying to dynamically call member associations on an object

```
@user.account.id.inspect #This will inspect user's account id as normal
@user.group.id.inspect #Same as above only with group id
@user.foo.id.inspect #etc, etc, etc...
```

This much is straight forward. On to the problem at hand...

I want to loop though all possible :has_one associations and do like above, only dynamically.

```
User.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_one).each do |association|
    #this works as normal
    association.name #returns "account", "group", "foo", etc...

    #The following won't work (Obviously)
    @user.{association.name}.id

    #I'm trying to find an idiom which
    #will essentially allow me to ninja swap "{association.name}"
    #with "account", "group", "foo", etc... Such that:
    #@user.{association.name}.id
    #...is functionally the same as @user.account.id, @user.group.id, @user.foo.id, etc...
end
```

FYI, the proper idiom in PHP would be similar to this:

```
$user->${$association->name}->id; #parses out to $user->account->id
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user.send(association.name).id should work.

Comment: This answer is perfectly cromulent